# Printed hex color code doesn't match with real background color

Tags: javascript

The purpose of my website is to find a hex color code by hitting a button, while the website's background is randomly changed by itself. However, when the button is clicked, the printed color code does not match with the current background color. how can I fix this?

```js
const infiniteColorChange = setInterval(() => {
  setColor()
  }, 5000);

function setColor() {
   document.body.style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor(); 
  } 

function getRandomColor() {
  for(let y = 0; y < 16777215; y++) {
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215);
    return "#" + randomNumber.toString(16);
  }
}

function stopColor() {
  clearInterval(infiniteColorChange);
  document.getElementById("hexcode").innerHTML = getRandomColor(); // printed code does not match with bg
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!--<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>What color is it</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>What color is it ...</h1>
    
    <h2 id="hexcode"></h2>

    <div id="center">
        <input type="button" onclick="stopColor()" class="button" value="Find A Color Code For Me">        
    </div> <!-- onclick stop loop -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you generating another random color to show? You're literally never getting the color you've set.

You should have retrieved it from the `style` attribute (or store it somewhere).

```js
document.getElementById("hexcode").innerHTML = document.body.style.backgroundColor;
```

This at least shows something like `rgb(123, 45, 67)` that *matches* the background color. You may need some extra work if you want the `#rrggbb` format.

Comment: You are not running setColor()

Comment: @MetBr OP's code shows a `setInterval` that calls `setColor()` every 5 seconds.

Comment: ow yeah interesting way i just noticed on top

Answer (score 0):

Your code in the `stopColor` function invokes the `getRandomColor` function, which generates a new random color, rather than using the one that was present when the button was clicked.

You can solve this by adding a new variable that always has the current color in it and referencing that variable in the `stopColor` function. (You could also just access the current document background color, but storing it in a variable is a bit more scalable.)

Also (FYI), don't use [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#security_considerations) if you can avoid it (which is almost always) because it has security and performance implications to it. Since you aren't reading or writing HTML anyway, use [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

```js
let currentColor = null; // Will always hold the current color

const infiniteColorChange = setInterval(() => {
  setColor()
  }, 5000);

function setColor() {
   currentColor = getRandomColor(); // Store the color for use elsewhere
   document.body.style.backgroundColor = currentColor; 
  } 

function getRandomColor() {
  for(let y = 0; y < 16777215; y++) {
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215);
    return "#" + randomNumber.toString(16);
  }
}

function stopColor() {
  clearInterval(infiniteColorChange);
  document.getElementById("hexcode").textContent = currentColor; // Access current color
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!--<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>What color is it</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>What color is it ...</h1>
    
    <h2 id="hexcode"></h2>

    <div id="center">
        <input type="button" onclick="stopColor()" class="button" value="Find A Color Code For Me">        
    </div> <!-- onclick stop loop -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling getRandomColor twice: once for the background and once for the hex code display. They won't match. Instead, use a variable and set it to the result of the function

```js
let randomColor;
const infiniteColorChange = setInterval(() => {
  setColor()
  }, 5000);

function setColor() {
   randomColor = getRandomColor();
   document.body.style.backgroundColor = randomColor; 
  } 

function getRandomColor() {
  for(let y = 0; y < 16777215; y++) {
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215);
    return "#" + randomNumber.toString(16);
  }
}

function stopColor() {
  clearInterval(infiniteColorChange);
  document.getElementById("hexcode").innerHTML = randomColor; 
}
```

Comment: There are already two answers that state the same thing as this. Since your answer doesn't add anything new, there's no value in adding it.